# intra ethernet interface of a router

Tags: ping, interface, mikrotik

Please I need some clearification. Is it possible to ping from one interface of a router to another interface of thesame router ?
Assuming router R1 with LAN interfaces e1 and e2. can i ping e2(destination) interface from e1(source).

Answer (score 0):

Sure, if there's a route connecting them. You can ping localhost as well, can't you?

Comment: by default, after adding ip to both interface, without adding firewall rule, i taught i should be able to ping them. Note: am using mikrotik routeros on with gns3. when ip were added to the interface, some route were created automatically in the table. but still they can not ping each other

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if the L3 device (router) is configured to permit it.